# React context (hooks) not updating all references

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, use-context

I am trying to implement a modal with a custom close callback. I did this with an useState hook that stores this method and executes it in an, already define, closeModal().
My problem is when I try to use the closeModal from context, the callback persists with the initial value, not the updated one.

```js
function ModalProvider({ children }) {
  const [component, setComponent] = useState<React.ReactNode>(null);
  const [styles, setStyles] = useState<React.CSSProperties>(null);
  const [onClose, setOnClose] = useState<() => void>(null);

  const openModal = ({
    component,
    containerStyles,
    onClose,
  }: OpenModalProps) => {
    setComponent(component);
    setStyles(containerStyles);
    setOnClose(() => onClose);
  };

  const closeModal = () => {
    onClose?.();

    setComponent(null);
    setStyles(null);
    setOnClose(null);
  };

  return (
    <ModalContext.Provider value={{ component, styles, openModal, closeModal }}>
      {children}
    </ModalContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

So here I using in two points, the button and the custom hook useClickOutside. When I click the button it works properly but when the event is catch from the hook what happen is that the modal closes but the onClose is not executed because is null.

```js
function Modal() {
  const { component, styles, closeModal } = useContext(ModalContext);
  const contentRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  const [stopScrolling, continueScrolling] = useStopScrolling();

  useClickOutside(contentRef, closeModal);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!component) continueScrolling();
    if (component) stopScrolling();
  }, [component]);

  if (!component) return <></>;

  return (
    <>
      <S.ModalWrapper>
        <section style={styles} ref={contentRef}>
          <button onClick={closeModal}>x</button>
          {component}
        </section>
      </S.ModalWrapper>
    </>
  );
}
```

```js
function useClickOutside(ref, onClickOutside: () => void) {
  const handleClickOutside = (event) => {
    if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
      onClickOutside();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
    };
  }, [ref]);
}
```

I use this method on other app points and also fails but I think this could be enough to found the problem. Thanks.

### Edit

This is how I invoke the modal

```js
      openModal({
        component: <QuickView product={product} close={closeModal} />,
        containerStyles: {
          width: "80%",
          maxWidth: "1000px",
          height: "auto",
          backgroundColor: "transparent",
        },
        onClose: () => {
          const as = router.asPath;
          router.push(as, as, { shallow: true });
        },
      });
```

Comment: Note the `component` you pass to `openModal` will contain the stale `closeModal` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there are multiple places in your code where `closeModal` is captured in closures without being declared a dependency, it has the potential to be invoked after becoming stale.

In that case it would be easier to make sure that it never has a stale reference to `onClose`, and you can do that by defining it with `useRef()` instead of `useState()`:

```
  const [component, setComponent] = useState<React.ReactNode>(null);
  const [styles, setStyles] = useState<React.CSSProperties>(null);
  // const [onClose, setOnClose] = useState<() => void>(null);
  const onCloseRef = useRef<() => void>(null);

  const openModal = ({
    component,
    containerStyles,
    onClose,
  }: OpenModalProps) => {
    setComponent(component);
    setStyles(containerStyles);
    // setOnClose(() => onClose);
    onCloseRef.current = onClose;
  };

  const closeModal = () => {
    // onClose?.();
    onCloseRef.current?.();

    setComponent(null);
    setStyles(null);
    // setOnClose(null);
    onCloseRef.current = null;
  };
```

Comment: @MiguelRodriguez can you edit your question and provide the code for the component in which `openModal` is consumed from the context and called?

Comment: @MiguelRodriguez I highly recommend linting with [`eslint-plugin-react-hooks`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks) to detect stale closure problems like this automatically.

Comment: I just add the code where I invoke the openModal